# Java thread competing after notifyAll

Tags: java, concurrency

I was wondering what will happen in this situation: I have 10 threads waiting (using `wait`) on some `lockObject` and 1 thread (lets call it `X` thread) trying to enter a synchronized by `lockObject` block. So will this `X` thread waiting to enter a synchronized block will be executed last? A don't see documentation to tell something about this. But in practice I tried this and `X` thread is executed always last. I know that "in practice" is not a proof when we are talking about concurrency, but still ... am I missing something or ?
Thanks in advance.

P.S.
This is the code I mean:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Object lock = new Object();

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            String currentThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            try {

                synchronized (lock) {
                    System.out.println("Start waiting: " + currentThreadName);
                    lock.wait();
                    System.out.println("End of synchronized: " + currentThreadName);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Thead enddds: " + currentThreadName);

        });

        t.setName("Thread: " + i);
        t.start();
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        synchronized (lock) {

            new Thread(() -> {
                Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
                System.out.println("X Threaaaaaaaad is starteeeeed");
                synchronized (lock) {
                    System.out.println("X Threaaaaaaaad");
                }
            }).start();

            Thread.sleep(100);
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an MCVE. Threads that have called `wait` on an object don't own that object's monitor.

Answer (score 0):

If the 10 threads are waiting on the `lockobject` then the new thread `x` will be executed immediately, because all the other threads are waiting.

When a thread goes into the a wait state using after the `wait()` call, **it release the lock on the object**. So the new thread will acquire the object lock and start execution. All the 10 threads will come to life when some thread calls the `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on the same object, otherwise they will be waiting for forever.

The actual execution of the threads will depend on the scheduling, but availability of the lock on the `lockobject` will make the thread `x`, start it's execution immediately.

Comment: I don't ask my question right, sorry about that.
I mean the following: in the main thread we have this
`synchronized(lockObject){
    Thread.sleed(3000);
    lockObject.notifyAll();
}`

And while the main thread is sleeping 10 threads use `wait` and another one (`X` thread) try to enter a block  synhcornized by `lockObject`.
So after main thread exits from this synchronized block the execution of threads will start. But in practice `X` thread is always the last executed.But I don't see anything in documentation about that.
Thans for youer attention.

Comment: @DPM the order of the thread execution is not guaranteed. Can you provide the complete code.